# CSS help required - block layout variation by media query - flex?

Tags: html, css

HTML5/CSS is not one of my strong points. I have a simple requirement - three DIVs to be laid out differently according to screen size, for which I am using @media declarations.

```
Layout 1                                Layout 2

+----- container -----------------+    +----- container ---------------------+
| +-----------------------------+ |    | +------------+  +-----------------+ |
| | header text                 | |    | | thumbnail  |  | header text     | |
| +-----------------------------+ |    | | image      |  +-----------------+ |
| +------------+  +-------------+ |    | |            |  +-----------------+ |
| | thumbnail  |  | body text   | |    | +------------+  | body text body  | |
| | image      |  | body text   | |    |                 | text body text  | |
| |            |  | body text   | |    |                 | body text ..... | |
| +------------+  +-------------+ |    |                 +-----------------+ | 
+---------------------------------+    +-------------------------------------+
```

The basic markup is:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="header">header text</div>
  <div id="thumbnail"><a href="xxx"><img src="yyy" /></a></div>
  <div id="bodytext">Some free-form text to be wrapped</div>
</div>
```

Thumbnail images are a fixed size. My effort so far is:

Layout 1 uses float:left for `thumbnail` and `bodytext` divs.
Layout 2 uses padding-left: [image width]px; on `header` and `bodytext` divs, and absolute positioning of `thumbnail`.

but it just all feels wrong and hacky, and I'm concerned about fragility across browser/device implementations.

Is there something more fit-for-purpose e.g. flex?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Note that the `<img>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash in HTML and never has.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the [**CSS Grid**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid) solution. Please view it in full screen to get the solution. Play with the [**Grid Generator**](https://cssgrid-generator.netlify.com/).

```css
#container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-column-gap: 10px;
  grid-row-gap: 10px;
}

#header {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 3;
}

#thumbnail {
  grid-area: 2 / 1 / 3 / 2;
}

#bodytext {
  grid-area: 2 / 2 / 3 / 3;
}

@media (max-width:600px) {
  #header {
    grid-area: 1 / 2 / 2 / 3;
  }
  #thumbnail {
    grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2;
  }
  #bodytext {
    grid-area: 2 / 2 / 3 / 3;
  }
}

/* Extra Styling for Snippet */

#container > div { background: #5548B0; color: #fff; text-align: center; font-size: 2em; padding: 5%; }
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="header">Header Text</div>
  <div id="thumbnail">
    <a href="stackoverflow.com"><img src="https://loremflickr.com/320/240"></a>
  </div>
  <div id="bodytext">Some free-form text to be wrapped</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Note that the `<img>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash in HTML and never has.

Comment: Didn't know about 'grid', so I will find out more.... but... this seems not to satisfy the arrangement on layout 2 where headertext is only as tall as it needs to be to render its content.

Comment: Do you mean you want to adjust the headertext element to a fixed height?

Comment: No - in layout 2, headertext is free to assume whatever height is required to render its content, and then bodytext should be positioned directly underneath it, ignoring the height of thumbnail.

Answer (score 1):

CSS grid seems to be the way to go. The modification I've made to Manoj's answer is to include the `min-content` directive to force a row to be the smallest height required to render content, and then rowspan the thumbnail cell over rows 1 and 2.

```css
#container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 320px 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: min-content 1fr;
  grid-column-gap: 8px;
}

#header {
  font-size: 2em;
  color: white;
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 2;
}

#thumbnail {
  grid-row: 1 / span 2;
  grid-column: 1;
}

#bodytext {
  color: red;
  grid-row:2;
  grid-column: 2;
}

@media (max-width:600px) {
  #header {
    grid-column: 1 / span 2;
  }
  #thumbnail {
      grid-row:2;
      grid-column: 1;
  }
}

/* Extra Styling for Snippet */

#container > div { 
     background: #5548B0; 
     text-align: center; 
 }
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="header">Header Text</div>
  <div id="thumbnail">
    <a href="stackoverflow.com"><img src="https://loremflickr.com/320/240"></a>
  </div>
  <div id="bodytext">Some free-form text to be wrapped. Some free-form text to be wrapped. Some free-form text to be wrapped. Some free-form text to be wrapped.</div>
</div>
```